# TikZDevice:  Add \caption{} and \label{} to TikZ diagram using R

Tags: r, latex, ggplot2, tikz

I've created a for loop that outputs several plots (via ggplot2) from R into a single .tex file using the `tikzDevice` package.  This makes it easier to include multiple diagrams from within a latex document using a single command that points to the .tex file outputted from R (say 'diagrams.tex'): `\include{diagrams}`.

However, I would also like to wrap each tikzpicture with the `\begin{figure}` environment, so that I can insert two additional lines into each respective figure: `\caption{}` and `\label{}`.

Question: is there a way to include the figure wrapper, caption, and label latex commands directly, for each respective ggplot image (from my R loop), in the outputted .tex file?

Here is reproducible R code that generates a file 'diagrams.tex' containing 3 ggplots:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tikzDevice)

## Load example data frame
A1 = as.data.frame(rbind(c(4.0,1.5,6.1),
c(4.0,5.2,3.5),
c(4.0,3.4,4.3),
c(4.0,8.2,7.3),
c(4.0,2.9,6.3),
c(6.0,3.9,6.6),
c(6.0,1.5,6.1),
c(6.0,2.7,5.3),
c(6.0,2.9,7.4),
c(6.0,3.7,6.0),
c(8.0,3.9,4.2),
c(8.0,4.1,3.5),
c(8.0,3.7,5.8),
c(8.0,2.5,7.5),
c(8.0,4.1,3.5)))
names(A1) = c("state","rmaxpay","urate")

i = 2

## name output file
tikz( 'diagrams.tex' )

for (i in 2:4){     #begin LOOP

st = i*2

df = NULL
df = subset(A1, state == st , select = c(2:3))

print(              # start print

ggplot(df, aes(rmaxpay,urate)) + geom_point() 

  )                 # end print

  }         #end LOOP

dev.off()
```

Comment: The 'caption' and 'label' go outside the 'tikzpicture' environment but within 'figure' environments which the .tex files you are producing are intended to be inserted in. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226961/what-is-the-correct-way-to-caption-a-tikzpicture

Comment: True - so what I would need is to wrap \begin{tikzpicture} with \begin{figure}...and then also include \caption{} and \label{} outside tikzpicture but inside figure.  Good point - I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a way to do this with plot hooks but as it is you can do it by using the `console` option and `sink()`:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tikzDevice)

## Load example data frame
A1 = as.data.frame(rbind(c(4.0,1.5,6.1),
c(4.0,5.2,3.5),
c(4.0,3.4,4.3),
c(4.0,8.2,7.3),
c(4.0,2.9,6.3),
c(6.0,3.9,6.6),
c(6.0,1.5,6.1),
c(6.0,2.7,5.3),
c(6.0,2.9,7.4),
c(6.0,3.7,6.0),
c(8.0,3.9,4.2),
c(8.0,4.1,3.5),
c(8.0,3.7,5.8),
c(8.0,2.5,7.5),
c(8.0,4.1,3.5)))
names(A1) = c("state","rmaxpay","urate")

i = 2
fn <- "diagrams.tex"
if(file.exists(fn)) file.remove(fn)

for (i in 2:4){     #begin LOOP

  st = i*2

  df = NULL
  df = subset(A1, state == st , select = c(2:3))

  cat("\\begin{figure}\n", file = fn, append=TRUE)
  sink(fn, append=TRUE)
  tikz(console = TRUE)
    print(              # start print
      ggplot(df, aes(rmaxpay,urate)) + geom_point() 
    )                 # end print
  dev.off()
  sink()
  cat(paste("\\caption{figure}\\label{fig:",i,"}\n",sep=""), file = fn, append=TRUE)
  cat("\\end{figure}\n", file = fn, append=TRUE)

}         #end LOOP
```